# XAML Binding to indexer with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to bind some property to an indexer with multiple parameters.

```
public decimal this[CalculationType calcType, AmountSource source]
{
    get
    {
        var foundRemittance = this.RemittanceAmounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CalculationType == calcType);
        if (foundRemittance != null)
        {
            return foundRemittance[source];
        }
        return 0.0m;
    }
}
```

my binding :

```
Value="{Binding Path=WorkingEntity.AmountDetails[{x:Static edm:CalculationType.RRQRPC}\,{x:Static edm:AmountSource.Applicable}]}"
```

No matter what I do the value doesn't show up.

[The whole code Here](https://paste.ofcode.org/DGHrG2ZRsUKnNvrNydwwvj)

The indexer returned value from the Watch :

[image]

Comment: I tested this and found that it works with an indexed property with two `int` parameters (e.g. `this[int x, int y]`), but it's not working with enums. I put `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` on the binding, and for the enum indexer it tells me `At level 1 - for AmountDetails[] found accessor <null>` -- while it has no trouble locating an [int, int] accessor overload on the same instance of the same class.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Cool infos. Do you know why it's like that ?  How can I work around that issue, other than using magic number ?

Comment: If I add an indexer `public String this[object a, object b]`, it gets invoked with strings `"{x:Static local:CalculationType.RRQRPC}"` and `"{x:Static local:AmountSource.Applicable}"`. So the XAML parser isn't parsing those x:Static things.

Comment: Interesting... so I might have to use a Converter.

Comment: It's gonna be a converter, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this and found that a binding works with an indexed property with two int parameters (e.g. `this[int x, int y]`), but it's not working with enums. I put `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` on the binding, and for the enum indexer it tells me `At level 1 - for AmountDetails[] found accessor <null>` -- while a nearby binding has no trouble locating an [int, int] indexer overload on the same instance of the same class.

If I add an indexer `public String this[object a, object b]`, it gets invoked with strings `"{x:Static local:CalculationType.RRQRPC}`" and `"{x:Static local:AmountSource.Applicable}"` for the two indexer parameters. So the XAML parser isn't parsing those `x:Static` things.

Here's how I'd do it. It's not quite as clean as what you wanted, but it works.

If you need to bind varying values of the two indexer parameters, you could write a somewhat similar multivalue converter and use a multibinding.

```
public class AmountDetailsIndexer : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public AmountDetailsIndexer()
    {
    }

    public AmountDetailsIndexer(CalculationType ctype, AmountSource asource)
    {
        CalculationType = ctype;
        AmountSource = asource;
    }

    public CalculationType CalculationType { get; set; }
    public AmountSource AmountSource { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(Object value, Type type, Object converterParameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var details = value as AmountDetails;

        return details[CalculationType, AmountSource];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(Object value, Type type, Object converterParameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<!-- Constructor with parameters -->
<Label 
    Content="{Binding AmountDetails, 
              Converter={local:AmountDetailsIndexer RRQRPC, Applicable}}"
    />

<!-- 
Parameterless constructor. More typing, but here you get intellisense 
when you set the properties 
-->
<Label 
    Content="{Binding AmountDetails, 
              Converter={local:AmountDetailsIndexer CalculationType=RRQRPC, AmountSource=Applicable}}"
    />
```

Using either this type of thing, or a multivalueconverter, I think it should be relatively trivial to write a generalized multiple indexer that uses reflection.

## UPDATE

Here's the generalized version using reflection.

```
public class Indexer : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public Indexer(object a0)
    {
        _arguments.Add(a0);
    }
    public Indexer(object a0, object a1)
    {
        _arguments.Add(a0);
        _arguments.Add(a1);
    }
    public Indexer(object a0, object a1, object a2)
    {
        _arguments.Add(a0);
        _arguments.Add(a1);
        _arguments.Add(a2);
    }
    public Indexer(object a0, object a1, object a2, object a3)
    {
        _arguments.Add(a0);
        _arguments.Add(a1);
        _arguments.Add(a2);
        _arguments.Add(a3);
    }

    private List<object> _arguments = new List<object>();

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(Object value, Type type, Object converterParameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var argTypes = _arguments.Select(p => p.GetType()).ToList();

        //  Indexers with the correct number of parameters
        var sameAryIndexers = value.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(prop => 
                prop.Name == "Item"
                //  Must have same number of parameters
                && prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == argTypes.Count)
            .ToList();

        var indexerProperties =
            sameAryIndexers
            .Where(prop =>
                prop.GetIndexParameters()
                    .Select(pi => pi.ParameterType)
                    .Zip(argTypes, (paramType, argType) => paramType.Equals(argType))
                    .All(b => b)
            ).ToList();

        //  If no exact match, try overloads. This is sketchy, if you ask me. 
        if (indexerProperties.Count != 1)
        {
            indexerProperties =
                sameAryIndexers
                .Where(prop =>
                    prop.GetIndexParameters()
                        .Select(pi => pi.ParameterType)
                        .Zip(argTypes, (paramType, argType) => paramType.IsAssignableFrom(argType))
                        .All(b => b)
                ).ToList();
        }

        if (indexerProperties.Count != 1)
        {
            var argTypeNames = String.Join(", ", argTypes.Select(t => t.Name));

            throw new Exception($"Unable to resolve overload: Input arguments {argTypeNames}, {indexerProperties.Count} matching indexers.");
        }

        try
        {
            var x = indexerProperties.First().GetValue(value, _arguments.ToArray());

            return x;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(Object value, Type type, Object converterParameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected bool IsTypesAssignableFrom(IEnumerable<Type> to, IEnumerable<Type> from)
    {
        return to.Zip(from, (tt, tf) => tt.IsAssignableFrom(tf)).All(b => b);

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Label 
    Content="{Binding AmountDetails, 
              Converter={local:Indexer 
                            {x:Static local:CalculationType.RRQRPC}, 
                            {x:Static local:AmountSource.Applicable}}}"
    />

<!-- 
BEWARE
As far as XAML is concerned, we're passing it the strings "123" and "345".
But {Binding AmountDetails[123, 345]} already works, so hey.
-->
<Label 
    Content="{Binding AmountDetails, 
              Converter={local:Indexer 123, 345}}"
    />
```

Comment: while an objectdataprovider is the intended solution for such a scenario this one certainly is more readable

Comment: @Dbl How would you do that with an `ObjectDataProvider`?

Comment: <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ADUsers" ObjectType="{x:Type src:RetrievCustomData}"
                MethodName="GetSome">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <sys:Int32>20</sys:Int32>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters><

Comment: @Dbl That calls an indexer?

Comment: @EdPlunkett obviously not - but you can write a generic version of it to swiftly do what you are doing here

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a custom MarkupExtension to be able to use {x:static} (and other extensions) in indexers. Here's a simple example supporting one parameter, you'd need to adapt it to support the amount of parameters required:

```
    public class FormattedPropertyPathExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Parameter1 { get; set; }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var formattedPath = string.Format(Path, Parameter1);
            var valueTarget = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
            if ((valueTarget.TargetProperty as PropertyInfo)?.PropertyType == typeof(PropertyPath))
            {
                return new PropertyPath(formattedPath);
            }

            return formattedPath;
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
Binding="{Binding Path={extensions:FormattedPropertyPath Path=Your.Binding.Path[{0}], Parameter1={x:Static ns:MyClass.MyKeyProperty}}}"
```